# Macbook plays blips of audio while muted

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, sound-volume

When I have my M1 Macbook Pro 14" running Ventura 13.3.1 muted with some audio playing (a YouTube vid, for example), it frequently plays a split second of audio. I don't see any visual indication that it has actually unmuted, but the audio definitely plays and it's quite jarring. Any theories for why this could be happening?